# Deploying Solidity smart contract on Hedera Hashgraph

Tags: hedera-hashgraph

Hi Everyone I have write smart contract for ERC-20 and deploy it to ethereum  network. Can I use the same smart contract to deploy Hedera network with out any code change. So I can use by existing smart contarct of ethereum for Hedera.

Answer for this confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  Hedera has smart contracts implemented by an standard EVM (Besu's EVM library).  It is very close to fully compatible with Ethereum/EVM. Many contracts will work without change.

There is a facility called the "JSON-RPC relay" which makes the network appear to be completely EVM compatible from the point of view of tools and wallets.

With some there will be issues with Hedera features that interact with Ethereum features - most of these will concern fees, but some will involve Hedera's native *accounts* (which have no Ethereum or EVM equivalent).

See the recent post ["EVM Equivalence: Unveiling Hedera's Strategy for Enhanced Programmability and Network Adoption"](https://hedera.com/blog/evm-equivalence-unveiling-hederas-strategy-for-enhanced-programmability-and-network-adoption) and the [official Hedera smart contract documentation](https://docs.hedera.com/hedera/core-concepts/smart-contracts).

- The latter page has a [detailed table](https://docs.hedera.com/hedera/core-concepts/smart-contracts/hederas-evm-equivalence-goals-and-exceptions) of differences that you might run in to, you can judge for yourself whether any of these will impact the contract(s) you intend to deploy.

Comment: I'll add my 2c here: EVM-compatibility is a spectrum, and there are a number of edge cases that you need to be aware of and/or work around if you're already familiar with Ethereum SC/ DApp development, and begin to work on Hedera. I've given a talk about this before, [here are the slides](https://blog.bguiz.com/presentations/evm-on-hedera/). Press `S` for speaker notes, which has far more detail.